# Interpretation of Characteristic function of probability density function for a classical system

Tags: fourier-transform, probability

Can the characteristic function ( fourier transform ) of a probability density function in position space for a **classical** system be related to its momentum space probability density function in any sense ?

Say for a particle in SHM of amplitude a . Its position space probability density function

$ W (x) = \frac{1} {\pi \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

Can its fourier transform be anyhow related with its momentum space probability density function , which is

$ \phi(p) = \frac{1} {\pi \sqrt{ p_0^2 -p^2}} $

Comment: There is no reason why it should...classical probability densities are naturally set in phase space, and not in configuration or momentum space only.

Comment: I wonder what kind of probability density functions in real space and in momentum space can have infinities at x=±a and at p=±p0, respectively.